# Configurar localhost pra exibir warnings de envio de cabeçalho

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de configurar o apache no meu localhost para que eu possa visualizar os warnings de envio de cabeçalho.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by…

É muito comum desenvolver o projeto no localhost ele funcionar corretamente, deixar algum detalhe escapar e só perceber o problema depois do deploy.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta. Mas dá uma olhada na documentação do apacha sobre LogLevel (por exemplo LogLevel debug rewrite:trace3) 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode configurar a exibição de erros em dois lugares no php.ini ou diretamente em um arquivo.

php.ini

Abra o arquivo e adicione ou modifique a linha:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Isso diz para exibir todos os tipos de erros e warnings `E_ALL` é o suficiente porém no php5.3 alguns warnings foram separados para `E_STRICT`, então manter os dois é mais questão de compatibilidade e certeza de que todos os tipos de erros/warnings serão exibidos.

Por arquivo

Pode exibir os erros/warnings de apenas um arquivo em particular com o uso das funções `error_reporting()` e `ini_set()`.

A primeira função sobrescreve o valor padrão(que vem do php.ini) do da diretiva `display_errors` para exibir os erros outro valor possível de passar é `-1` que tem o mesmo efeito que `true`. A segunda função defini o nível de erros que serão exibidos.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$str = 'inválido'
```